# Cant find module

Tags: javascript

Trying to make some economy commands, currently trying to make the command that sends the total amount of coins, the message author has, to the message author. i continue to get "cant find module" errors. i have tried searching for this error, but i seem to not be able to find a solution.

My file construct - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sER3g.png

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "coins",
    descriptions: "shows how many coins you have",
    category: "Economy",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        //coins
        if(!coins[message.author.id]){
            coins[message.author.id] = {
                coins: 0
            };
        }
        let uCoins = coins[message.author.id].coins;

        let coinEmbed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            .setcolor("RANDOM")
            .addField("", uCoins);

        message.author.send(coinEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `let coins = require("../../coins.json");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the file structure you linked, your `require` is looking for the `coins.json` in the `commands` folder, as you only prefixed the file name with `../` once. In order to get your file, prefix the name with `../../`, so it goes up two folders. Your line would then look like this:

```
let coins = require("../../coins.json");
```

Comment: Thank you for this, im still a massive amateur to JS. this will help in any later commands i have

Answer (score 0):

If it is due to incorrect path you can use the code bellow. It will find the json file anywhere in your code.

```js
const { join } = require("path");
let coins = require(`${join(process.cwd(), "coins.json")}`);
```